# What does “likelihood” mean in the image?

Tags: machine-learning, maximum-likelihood, descriptive-statistics, likelihood, likelihood-ratio

It is about insurance fraud. The image 2 shows the result of analysis with likelihood of claim referral, which is the target variable, from the previous analysis, image 1, on historical referral data. How should I interpret the likelihood in the image?

The description from the article is as follows:

- The link to the document: http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings14/1837-2014.pdf
- Analysis of Historical Referrals

This first analysis allows insurance companies to apply analytics for more consistent claim referrals to the SIU. For
this analysis, the target variable is a history of claim referrals to the special investigative unit. This target can be
adjusted to just use the referrals of those claim adjusters that are considered the most experienced or most
effective. The independent variables considered in the analysis are the details of the claims. The result of the
analysis is, based on the historical claim referrals, the likelihood that a new claim should be referred to the
investigative unit.
The chart below shows the partial results of a decision tree based on an analysis of a database of automobile
insurance bodily injury coverage closed claims. The dataset included an indicator if the claim was referred to an
investigative unit, and also included the details of the claim (injury details, accident severity, claimant
characteristics, location, and payment information).

[image]
Image 1.

It can be determined from this analysis which factors were associated with increased claim referrals. These characteristics included the severity of the injury, the location of the accident, and whether the claimant was
represented by an attorney. While the decision tree results are shown here, three separate predictive models were developed: Decision Tree, Neural Network, and Logistic Regression. Ultimately, the predicted referral was determined by an Ensemble model which used the combined effect of the three models to produce a more accurate prediction.
The distribution of the predicted likelihood of referral for the claims in the bodily injury dataset is shown below.

[image]
Image 2

Based on this distribution, a cutoff score could be chosen such that claims above a certain point would automatically be referred to the investigative unit. These claims could be sent directly to the SIU, allowing experienced claim adjusters to spend their time on those claims the model classifies as being borderline in regards to fraud likelihood.

Comment: I am afraid you need to refer to some kind of documentation of ask the person who provided those results. Certainly it does *not* seem to have anything to do with likelihood as understood by statisticians.

Comment: From the document you likened I'd guess that what they mean is they use "likelihood" as synonym to "probability".